# How to move another controller without referring previous controller's js file [Angularjs]

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a single page application. Here I moved parent controller to child controller using state.go("Child").

In child controller takes all js and css files referred from parent controller view.

Here I want to refer new js files and css without referred parent js and css files.

Please share your views. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add common `custom.css` file in your project and mention this in `index.html` page. Also for styling html tags yoc can use different #id or .class.

Comment: Ya. good. But here i am rendering controls using js and theme css file. A version of  control's js and theme css referred in  parent control page, and another different version of control's js and theme css referred in child control. In my situation if i referred both js files in index, both will not works. If i comment one js another will be works fine. So here i planned to referred files in corresponding pages that is parent js in index, child js in its html page. Then only works what referred in index page. Hope you understand my problem.